# Angular deepCloned child component Input cannot be changed on UI

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material, ngrx

I have parent and child component.
In parent component there is `BehaviourSubject<SomeObject[]>()`.

```
export interface SomeObject(){
field: number;
...
editable: boolean
}
```

I cannot pass whole object to child component, I have to filter that before so input value look like this:

```
childInputData = parentBehaviourSubject.value.filter(x=>...);
```

On UI in child component I have icon edit which is visible if field `editable = false`, and after click on this icon it changed `editable = true` and enable some field to edit. My problem is that I want to pass cloned array as child input. When I changed

```
childInputData = _.cloneDeep(parentBehaviourSubject.value.filter(x=>...));
```

UI edit icon stop reacting on any click. And I really don't know why. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why exactly are you calling `filter(...)` on an object? This function is used for arrays. If you call `.value` on the behaviorsubject you are basically taking the current value of this object and ignore values, which will be emitted in the future.

If you want to pass the current value to the child component everytime you should `pipe` your value and subscribe to it (using `async` pipe).

The following code creates an observable of a copy of each emitted value from `parentBehaviourSubject`:

```
childInputData$ = parentBehaviourSubject.pipe(map( val => _.cloneDeep(val) );
```

And in your HTML you can use the following code to pass this value to your child:

```
<child-component [childData]="childInputData$ | async">
...
```

Comment: I missed [] in description - it should be BehaviourSubject<SomeObject[]>(). But true - taking only value was my issue, at some point it lead to break for all application. I needed to filter this behavioreSubject base one data from ui dynamically and I did not came up with great idea of doing this. Finally i create custom pipe like  [childData] = parentBehaviourSubject | async | customPipe:dataFromUI

Comment: This does of course work as well. Nevertheless I prefer my approach, sind this derived observable and the corresponding custom logic is scoped to this component. If you want to reuse and generalize this logic, of course a pipe is the better approach.